# How to show list of items limited by default and should show remaining items on scrolling using angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular9

I have the following list of items.

Case a. If they are lessthan three items(ex: one or two or three items), then we need to show those items normally as usual(Coming fine).

Case b. If list of item are more than three(ex: four, five, six, ...), then we need to show list of items first three by default, then the remaining items should show on scrolling - `Not showing properly.`

Can anyone please help me regarding this(for Case b) in `angular` without using any `cdk-virtual-scroll`, Thanks in advance.

Created [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-fmfs5m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Expected Result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use

npm i ngx-infinite-scroll

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll